# Any point in waiting for Samsung 850 EVO?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I'm about to upgrade my MacBook Pro (13" mid 2012) with 16GB of RAM and an SSD. According to [this news article](http://www.legitreviews.com/storage-visions-2014-samsung-850-ssd-series-coming-this-summer_132297) Samsung's new 850 SSD series might be around the corner, and I'd much appreciate your opinion on whether I should wait for it or go with the current 840 EVO?

Is there really any more speed to be had over the MBP's SATA III interface than what the 840 EVO already delivers? The fact that the 850 series will still use SATA III would suggest so, but on the other hand [this post](http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/457172-why-storage-drive-speeds-dont-hit-their-theoretical-limits/) doesn't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself this, do you need a performance boost now or can you wait an unknown amount of time for a possibly unnoticeable difference between the 840 and 850 EVO?

I personally have an 840 EVO, install them all day long and before my EVO I had an Intel SSD. EVOs are great but the decision should be as simple as do you want it now or do it you want it later. No matter what you won't regret your decision.

Comment: Agree with this. There is always new tech that "might be around the corner", and if you're always waiting for it you might as well be chasing the pot of gold at the end of a rainbow

Comment: Fine advice from both of you. 840 EVO it is! =)